# Set company-wide Chrome theme

Tags: google-workspace

Our company uses G Suite.

I would like to create a color theme for Google Chrome. Then I'd like to have all accounts on our domain use this theme by default.

This will make it more clear for people when they are actually doing work (and their URL history is recorded to the company archives) versus when they are farting around.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about managing web browsers company wide (admin) not about using a web application (end user).

Comment: I wish I could +2 just for saying "farting around".

Answer (score 1):

Solution is discussed here:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?hl=en#general

Here is the place to do it:

[image]